# How to create a slanting border with css

Tags: html, css, transform

I want to cut my border as the image below displays:

[image]

They areas that are cut away should be transparent if possible.

This is my code at the moment:

```
.main {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
}

footer {
    height: 93px;
    background-color: #ff6138;
    position: relative;
}

.footer-info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 27px;
    left: 33px;
}

footer span {
    color: #ffff9d;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    font-size: 1.1875em;
}

footer .tel {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-left: 24px;
}

body {
    background-color: #ff9200;
}
```

Link to code http://jsfiddle.net/NpX23/

Comment: which browsers do you need to support? IE7? IE8?

Comment: cut a background image? or you want to do it with css only?

Comment: Use a background image. Most reliable option if your looking for full browser compatibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using :before/:after and `rotate`.

Add position:relative to `.main` and `footer`.

```
.main:after, footer:before {
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-1deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-1deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-1deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-1deg);
    transform: rotate(-1deg);
    z-index: -1;
}

.main:after {
    bottom: -20px;
}

footer:before {
    top: -20px;
}
```

Working:
http://jsfiddle.net/NpX23/8/

Comment: This is broken in my browser (the background peeks through).

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: It's more the fact that it doesn't work in wider screens. Minimized it works fine, but large, not so much.

Comment: I got a large screen and works fine. EDIT: Ok got it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something using the `:before` attribute without `rotate`:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NpX23/7/)

```
footer::before{
    content:' ';
    position:absolute;
    top:-25px;
    left:0;
    width: 0;
    height: 10px;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 1800px solid #ff9200;
}
```

And I put `overflow-x:hidden;` in `body`.

Answer (score 0):

Used to **[Rotate](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/)** **`property`** `css3` as  like this

```
.main {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

footer {
    height: 93px;
    background-color: #ff6138;
    position: relative;
    margin-top:20px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NpX23/3/)**

Comment: But the element should not be rotaded, only the border / edge should but cut that way.